# A new instance of a object within an anonymous function so I can use in an instance of a prototype object's function

Tags: javascript

Please for give me if I am not explaining my question very well.

So I have a CDN where the library has an anonymous function, within the function is an object called Phoria.CanvasRenderer...

```
(function() {
   "use strict";

   Phoria.CanvasRenderer = function(canvas)
   {
  Phoria.CanvasRenderer.superclass.constructor.call(this);

  this.canvas = canvas;
  this.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  return this;
  }; 
//Additional required functions below
```

I need to create a new instance of this object and I am doing it in a constructor of a prototype which I am guessing is incorrect...

```
var MyPrototype = {
init: function () {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    renderer = new Phoria.CanvasRenderer(canvas);      
          },
run: function () {
    //TODO stuff w/ renderer 
          }   
       };

function container_inintalizer() {
function P() { }
P.prototype = MyPrototype;
var p = new P();
p.init();
return p;
}

var obj = container_inintalizer();
obj.run();
```

I know that I am not instantiating correctly, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is "superclass"?

Comment: I do see there is a reference to the parent

Comment: The CDN is: [http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/phoria/scripts/phoria-renderer.js](http://www.kevs3d.co.uk/dev/phoria/scripts/phoria-renderer.js)  The only thing is that the parent is a prototype wrapped in an anonymous. I am just unclear how to reference.

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem with your code is.

Comment: I'm getting a reference error that says I cannot find variable Phoria @ `renderer = new Phoria.CanvasRenderer(canvas);`, if I do reference a new instance in a regular function and not a prototype it works perfectly fine. I can create a instance using NEW keyword but for some reason I am loosing scope within the constructor of my prototype. Again, the instance is an object within an anonymous function that is within a prototype that is wrapped in an anonymous function to start with. I placed a link from the source above if you want to take a look.